# Logically validating list of comparisons (inequalities) and returning the node color

Tags: python, performance, algorithm

Given an arbitrary list of operations as follows:

```
operation1 = [('Red', '<', 10)]
operation2 = [('Red', '<', 10), ('Blue', '>=', 10)]
operation3 = [('Red', '>', 1), ('Blue', '>=', 10)]
```

###### Constraints

1. A list of operations will have the following attributes:

   **Color:** String

   **Operator:** <, <=, >, >=, ==, !=

   **Value:** Integer or a Float
2. The list can contain maximum **n** operations

The first task is to validate whether the inequalities defined are logically valid and the second task is to identify a color when a value is given for a given list of operation.

Is there a better approach/algorithm/data structure to validation and finding a category? Are there any edge cases that are not currently tested? How can we optimize this code?

##### Example:

###### Task 1:

Logically validate whether the bounds defined are correct or not

1. `validate(operations=operation1)` should be `False`
2. `validate(operations=operation2)` should be `True`
3. `validate(operations=operation3)` should be `False`

###### Task 2:

The `find(operations=operation2, value=10)` should give `Blue` as the output since the value (10) falls/matches with the bounds of the second node in the list `operations2`.

#### Python Code

```
import operator
from copy import deepcopy
from decimal import Decimal
from typing import Callable, Dict, List, Optional, Set, Union

Number = Union[int, float, Decimal]

_operations: Dict[str, Callable] = {
    "<": operator.lt,
    "<=": operator.le,
    ">=": operator.ge,
    ">": operator.gt,
    "==": operator.eq,
    "!=": operator.ne,
}

_reverse_operations: Dict[str, Callable] = {
    "<": operator.ge,
    "<=": operator.gt,
    ">=": operator.lt,
    ">": operator.le,
    "==": operator.ne,
    "!=": operator.eq,
}


class Operation:
    def __init__(
        self,
        equality: str = "",
        number: Number = 0,
        color: str = "",
        right: Optional["Operation"] = None,
    ) -> None:
        self.number = number
        self.equality = equality
        self.color = color
        self.right = right

    def compare(self, value: Number):
        compare_function = _operations.get(self.equality)
        return compare_function(value, self.number)

    def reverse_compare(self, number: Number, value: Number):
        compare_function = _reverse_operations.get(self.equality)
        return compare_function(value, number)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"[{self.color} ({self.equality} {self.number})]"


def _insert_node(
    root_operations: Optional[Operation], operation: Operation
) -> Optional[Operation]:
    """
    Inserts the operation at the correct location
    in the linked list and returns the root

    Arguments:
        root_operations - The root of the linked list
        operation - The operation to be inserted

    Returns: a new root of the linked list
    """

    root = Operation(right=root_operations)
    node = root
    while node.right:
        parent = node
        node = node.right
        # if the numbers are same then we would need to check the operators
        if node.number == operation.number:
            match operation.equality:
                # if the operator is greater than, place the new operation after current
                case ">" | ">=":
                    node.right, operation.right = operation, node.right
                # if the operator is less than, place the new operation before current
                case "<" | "<=":
                    parent.right, operation.right = operation, node
            return root.right
        elif node.number > operation.number:
            # when the current number is greater than the operation number, insert it
            parent.right, operation.right = operation, node
            return root.right

    # place it at the end
    node.right = operation
    return root.right


def find(root_operations: Optional[Operation], value: Number) -> str:
    """
    Finds the color of a given value from the operations

    Arguments:
        root_operations - The root of the linked list

    Returns: the identified `operation.color` or empty string `""`
    """

    parent = Operation(equality="", right=root_operations)
    node = parent.right

    # Validate that the first operation includes all the smaller numbers
    if node and node.equality not in ["<", "<="]:
        return ""
    while node and node.right:
        node = node.right
    # Validate that the last operation includes all the smaller numbers
    if node and node.equality not in [">", ">="]:
        return ""

    node = parent.right
    while node:
        # if we are at the first node or the last node only validate that operator
        if (not parent.equality or not node.right) and node.compare(value):
            return node.color
        else:
            if node.equality in ["==", "!="] and node.compare(value):
                return node.color

            # Check whether the given value is in limit or not
            if (
                node.equality in [">=", ">"]
                and node.right
                and node.compare(value)
                and node.reverse_compare(node.right.number, value)
            ):
                return node.color
            if (
                node.equality in ["<=", "<"]
                and parent.equality
                and node.compare(value)
                and node.reverse_compare(parent.number, value)
            ):
                return node.color

        parent = node
        node = node.right

    return ""


def _generate_values(operations: List[Operation]) -> Set[Number]:
    """
    Generates values on the edges of the operations for validation

    Arguments:
        operations - List of operations

    Returns: list of numbers
    """

    numbers = set()
    for op in operations:
        numbers.add(op.number - 1)
        numbers.add(op.number)
        numbers.add(op.number + 1)
    return numbers


def create_list(operations: List[Operation]) -> Optional[Operation]:
    """
    Generates a linked list from List of Operations and returns the root node

    Arguments:
        operations - List of operations
    """
    copied: List[Operation] = deepcopy(operations)
    root: Optional[Operation] = copied.pop(0)
    for op in copied:
        root = _insert_node(root, op)
    return root


def validate(operations: List[Operation]) -> bool:
    """
    Validates the list of operations

    Arguments:
        operations - List of operations

    Returns: `True` if the operations are logically valid else `False`
    """

    first = create_list(operations)
    values = _generate_values(operations)
    categories = set([find(first, value) for value in values])
    return set([op.color for op in operations]) == categories


def print_list(root: Optional[Operation]) -> None:
    """
    Prints the linked list of Operations

    Arguments:
        root_operations - The root of the linked list
    """
    node = root
    while node:
        print(node, end=" ")
        node = node.right
    print()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    operations=[
        Operation("<", 10, "Red"),
    ]
    assert validate(operations) == False
    operations=[
        Operation("<", 10, "Red"),
        Operation(">=", 10, "Blue")
    ]
    assert validate(operations) == True
    operations=[
        Operation(">", 1, "Red"),
        Operation("<=", 10, "Blue")
    ]
    assert validate(operations) == False
    operations=[
        Operation(">", 1, "Red"),
        Operation(">=", 10, "Blue")
    ]
    assert validate(operations) == False
    operations=[
        Operation("<", 1, "Red"),
        Operation(">=", 10, "Blue")
    ]
    assert validate(operations) == False
    operations =[
        Operation("<=", 20, "Red"),
        Operation("<=", 40, "Blue"),
        Operation(">", 40, "Green"),
    ]
    assert validate(operations) == True
    operations =[
        Operation("<", 20, "Red"),
        Operation(">=", 20, "Blue"),
        Operation("<", 40, "Green"),
    ]
    assert validate(operations) == False
```

Comment: Making a wild guess: it seems like this is attempting to evaluate whether the union of all provided inequalities covers the entire real number line at least once. If that is the case, this code is somewhat close to working but somewhat broken and overcomplicated, and some of your test cases are both producing and asserting the wrong thing.

Comment: @Reinderien: The assumption for validating the inequalities is indeed correct. Can you please clarify which tests are incorrect from my code?

Comment: See edit; I kept all of your test cases but adjusted some of the expected outputs

Comment: Your edit constitutes answer invalidation so I've rolled it back. If you need further refinement, please file a new question.

Comment: Understood, thank you for the feedback! I'll be able to proceed based on your answer.

Answer (score 1):

### First pass

Somewhat superficially,

`deepcopy` is not necessary.

You would benefit from constraining your operation names to a `Literal`.

You should not leave your `Callable` unspecified; fill it in `[]`.

Your `Operation` conflates two things: the actual operation, and the linked list node. I think you should separate these into two classes, among other reasons because the actual operation can then be immutable, and can enforce non-`None` values for all of its members.

Some methods like `compare()` are missing return typehints `->`.

Many of your methods, such as `insert_node`, are conceptually centered around a main node like `root_operations`, which suggests that they should just be instance methods.

You're already this far into implementing and using a linked list, so you might as well implement an `__iter__`.

Your global functions that lead with `_` are presumably named that way to make them look like module-private symbols. Typically it's more common to omit the underscore and modify the definition of `__all__`.

What you're holding in strings like `<` is almost always an [inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_(mathematics)) and not an equality.

Consider adding convenience properties to your operator class to categorise the inequality.

It's not a great idea to use blank strings `''` as placeholder values; prefer `None`.

Contemporary Python no longer needs the `List` and `Set` symbols for typing; the built-in `list` and `set` suffice.

Don't `pop()`; instead tuple-splat-unpack via `root, *copied =`.

Nice test cases! Drop the `== True` and `== False` and replace with `assert` and `assert not`.

Don't `.get()` on your operation dictionaries. This should fail early, not contaminate your logic with a `None`.

```py
import operator
from dataclasses import dataclass
from numbers import Number
from typing import Callable, Optional, Iterable, Iterator, NamedTuple, Literal

BinOp = Callable[[Number, Number], Number]

OpName = Literal[
    '<', '<=',
    '>', '>=',
    '!=', '==',
]

OPERATIONS: dict[OpName, BinOp] = {
    '<': operator.lt,  '<=': operator.le,
    '>': operator.gt,  '>=': operator.ge,
    '!=': operator.ne, '==': operator.eq,
}

REVERSE_OPERATIONS: dict[OpName, BinOp] = {
    '<': operator.ge,  '<=': operator.gt,
    '>': operator.le,  '>=': operator.lt,
    '!=': operator.eq, '==': operator.ne,
}


class Operation(NamedTuple):
    inequality: OpName
    number: Number
    color: str

    def compare(self, value: Number) -> Number:
        compare_function = OPERATIONS[self.inequality]
        return compare_function(value, self.number)

    def reverse_compare(self, number: Number, value: Number) -> Number:
        compare_function = REVERSE_OPERATIONS[self.inequality]
        return compare_function(value, number)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'[{self.color} ({self.inequality} {self.number})]'

    @property
    def edges(self) -> set[Number]:
        x = self.number
        return {x - 1, x, x + 1}

    @property
    def in_equal(self) -> bool:
        return self.inequality in {'==', '!='}

    @property
    def in_less(self) -> bool:
        return self.inequality in {'<', '<='}

    @property
    def in_greater(self) -> bool:
        return self.inequality in {'>', '>='}


@dataclass
class Node:
    operation: Optional['Operation'] = None
    right: Optional['Node'] = None

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return ' '.join(str(n.operation) for n in self)

    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator['Node']:
        node = self
        while node:
            yield node
            node = node.right

    def generate_values(self) -> set[Number]:
        values = set()
        for node in self:
            values |= node.operation.edges
        return values

    def validate(self) -> bool:
        values = self.generate_values()
        categories = {self.find(value) for value in values}
        return {node.operation.color for node in self} == categories

    def insert_node(self, operation: Operation) -> Optional['Node']:
        """
        Inserts the operation at the correct location
        in the linked list and returns the root

        Arguments:
            root_operations - The root of the linked list
            operation - The operation to be inserted

        Returns: a new root of the linked list
        """

        root = parent = Node(right=self)
        new_node = Node(operation=operation)

        for node in self:
            # if the numbers are same then we would need to check the operators
            if node.operation.number == operation.number:
                if operation.in_greater:
                    # if the operator is greater than, place the new operation after current
                    node.right, new_node.right = new_node, node.right
                elif operation.in_less:
                    # if the operator is less than, place the new operation before current
                    parent.right, new_node.right = new_node, node
                return root.right

            if node.operation.number > operation.number:
                # when the current number is greater than the operation number, insert it
                parent.right, new_node.right = new_node, node
                return root.right

            parent = node

        # place it at the end
        node.right = new_node
        return root.right

    @property
    def last(self) -> 'Node':
        for node in self:
            pass
        return node

    def find(self, value: Number) -> Optional[str]:
        """
        Finds the color of a given value from the operations

        Returns: the identified `operation.color` or None`
        """

        parent = Node(right=self)

        # Validate that the first operation includes all the smaller numbers
        if not self.operation.in_less:
            return None

        # Validate that the last operation includes all the smaller numbers
        if not self.last.operation.in_greater:
            return None

        for node in parent.right:
            # if we are at the first node or the last node only validate that operator
            if (not parent.operation or not node.right) and node.operation.compare(value):
                return node.operation.color

            if node.operation.in_equal and node.operation.compare(value):
                return node.color

            # Check whether the given value is in limit or not
            if (
                node.operation.in_greater
                and node.right
                and node.operation.compare(value)
                and node.reverse_compare(node.right.operation.number, value)
            ):
                return node.color

            if (
                node.operation.in_less
                and parent.operation
                and node.operation.compare(value)
                and node.operation.reverse_compare(parent.operation.number, value)
            ):
                return node.operation.color

            parent = node

        return None


def create_list(operations: Iterable[Operation]) -> Node:
    """
    Generates a linked list from List of Operations and returns the root node

    Arguments:
        operations - List of operations
    """
    root_op, *copied = operations
    root = Node(root_op)
    for op in copied:
        root = root.insert_node(op)
    return root


def validate(operations: Iterable[Operation]) -> bool:
    """
    Validates the list of operations

    Arguments:
        operations - List of operations

    Returns: `True` if the operations are logically valid else `False`
    """

    first = create_list(operations)
    print(first)
    return first.validate()


def main() -> None:
    operations = (
        Operation('<', 10, 'Red'),
    )
    assert not validate(operations)

    operations = (
        Operation('<', 10, 'Red'),
        Operation('>=', 10, 'Blue'),
    )
    assert validate(operations)

    operations = (
        Operation('>', 1, 'Red'),
        Operation('<=', 10, 'Blue'),
    )
    assert not validate(operations)

    operations = (
        Operation('>', 1, 'Red'),
        Operation('>=', 10, 'Blue'),
    )
    assert not validate(operations)

    operations = (
        Operation('<', 1, 'Red'),
        Operation('>=', 10, 'Blue'),
    )
    assert not validate(operations)

    operations = (
        Operation('<=', 20, 'Red'),
        Operation('<=', 40, 'Blue'),
        Operation('>', 40, 'Green'),
    )
    assert validate(operations)

    operations = (
        Operation('<', 20, 'Red'),
        Operation('>=', 20, 'Blue'),
        Operation('<', 40, 'Green'),
    )
    assert not validate(operations)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

### Second pass

Now that we've demystified what you're actually attempting to do - evaluate complete coverage of the real number line by the union of all provided inequalities - we can see that the algorithm as presented is incorrect.

First the boundary conditions. You've expressed that you want to support floats in your `Number` (though you don't need to define this yourself; use `numbers.Real`). But then you test around a boundary with +1, 0 and -1, which ensures that your algorithm will only work for integers.

Also, your test cases (which, again, are an excellent idea) already demonstrate that your algorithm produces incorrect results. This test case is incorrect:

```
    operations=[
        Operation(">", 1, "Red"),
        Operation("<=", 10, "Blue")
    ]
    assert validate(operations) == False
```

If a number must be greater than 1 or less than or equal to 10, it can be anything; i.e. the entire number line is covered and this should be `True`. The last test case you presented is similarly incorrect.

A much simplified algorithm could look like:

1. Establish a working list of known intervals, initially empty.
2. For each inequality, decompose it into one or more new intervals.
3. For each new interval, check for overlap with all intervals in the known interval list.
4. Merge all intervals that overlap.
5. If at the end, there is exactly one interval that covers negative through positive infinity, then the reals are covered.

For your input scale this is good enough. For huge input scale, optimisation is possible by bisect-searching for intervals.

```
from itertools import chain
from numbers import Real
from typing import NamedTuple, Literal, Iterable, Iterator

INF = float('inf')


class Interval(NamedTuple):
    # The closed-ness of the interval is expressed opposite between the lower
    # and upper bound to facilitate natural sorting
    lower: Real
    lower_open: bool
    upper: Real
    upper_closed: bool

    @property
    def sortable_lower(self) -> tuple[Real, bool]:
        return self.lower, self.lower_open

    @property
    def sortable_upper(self) -> tuple[Real, bool]:
        return self.upper, self.upper_closed

    def overlaps(self, other: 'Interval') -> bool:
        return (
            (
                self.lower < other.upper or (
                    self.lower == other.upper and (other.upper_closed or not self.lower_open)
                )
            )
            and
            (
                self.upper > other.lower or (
                    self.upper == other.lower and (self.upper_closed or not other.lower_open)
                )
            )
        )

    def merge(self, other: 'Interval') -> 'Interval':
        return Interval(
            *min(self.sortable_lower, other.sortable_lower),
            *max(self.sortable_upper, other.sortable_upper),
        )

    def merge_into(self, intervals: Iterable['Interval']) -> Iterator['Interval']:
        new_interval = self
        for old_interval in intervals:
            if new_interval.overlaps(old_interval):
                new_interval = new_interval.merge(old_interval)
            else:
                yield old_interval
        yield new_interval


class Inequality(NamedTuple):
    symbol: Literal[
        '<', '<=',
        '>', '>=',
        '!=', '==',
    ]
    right: Real
    color: str

    def to_intervals(self) -> tuple[Interval, ...]:
        match self.symbol:
            case '<':  return Interval(-INF, False, self.right, False),
            case '<=': return Interval(-INF, False, self.right, True),
            case '>':  return Interval(self.right,  True, INF, True),
            case '>=': return Interval(self.right, False, INF, True),
            case '==': return Interval(self.right, False, self.right, True),
            case '!=': return (Interval(-INF, False, self.right, False),
                               Interval(self.right, True, INF, True))
            case _:
                raise ValueError(f'{self.symbol} is an invalid inequality symbol')


def covers_reals(ineqs: Iterable[Inequality]) -> bool:
    intervals = ()

    for new_interval in chain.from_iterable(
        ineq.to_intervals() for ineq in ineqs
    ):
        intervals = tuple(new_interval.merge_into(intervals))

    return (
        len(intervals) == 1
        and intervals[0].lower == -INF
        and intervals[0].upper == INF
    )


def test() -> None:
    ineqs = Inequality('<', 10, 'Red'),
    assert not covers_reals(ineqs)

    ineqs = (
        Inequality('<', 10, 'Red'),
        Inequality('>=', 10, 'Blue'),
    )
    assert covers_reals(ineqs)

    ineqs = (
        Inequality('>', 1, 'Red'),
        Inequality('<=', 10, 'Blue'),
    )
    assert covers_reals(ineqs)

    ineqs = (
        Inequality('>', 1, 'Red'),
        Inequality('>=', 10, 'Blue'),
    )
    assert not covers_reals(ineqs)

    ineqs = (
        Inequality('<', 1, 'Red'),
        Inequality('>=', 10, 'Blue'),
    )
    assert not covers_reals(ineqs)

    ineqs = (
        Inequality('<=', 20, 'Red'),
        Inequality('<=', 40, 'Blue'),
        Inequality('>', 40, 'Green'),
    )
    assert covers_reals(ineqs)

    ineqs = (
        Inequality('<', 20, 'Red'),
        Inequality('>=', 20, 'Blue'),
        Inequality('<', 40, 'Green'),
    )
    assert covers_reals(ineqs)

    ineqs = Inequality('!=', 0, 'Burnt Chartreuse'),
    assert not covers_reals(ineqs)

    ineqs = (
        Inequality('!=', 3, 'Sewer Sunrise'),
        Inequality('==', 3, 'Rancid Banana'),
    )
    assert covers_reals(ineqs)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Comment: I have edited the question and clarified on the process of identifying ambiguity and added decomposition of the process.

Comment: @abybaddi009 That still doesn't make any sense. Since the answer is in place, if you still need refinement consider filing a new question and going into more depth into the theoretical why and how of your data structure and business logic.

Comment: Ignore my previous comment, can you please take a look at the question?